# Does privilege to access review queue bypass peer review

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, privileges

In Privileges > access review queues when user is at 500 reputation points
allow the user to bypass peer reviews on his own post edits? That is, can I
now edit a post (question/answer) without review?

Comment: Or do I have to peer review my own edit?

Comment: [Edit Questions and Answers (w/o peer review)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege is awarded at 2000 rep.

Comment: Edits that you make to your own posts are never reviewed, unless it looks like vandalism / abuse but that is after the fact.

Comment: @2000 points.. Ok, thanks.

Comment: Your edits to other posts will still be reviewed.. Of course you won't get to review your own edits.. That will be done by other users